# How can I use C to change the last modified date of a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, file

Is there a C function call that can change the last modified date of a file or directory in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933(VS.85).aspx) function, for the directories, you have to use the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) function with the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag to get the directory handle and use it as the file handle parameter of the SetFileTime like this:

```
hFolder = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
```

Comment: thanks I was missing the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, but you save me a day

Answer (score 2):

Use SetFileTime:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetFileTime(
  __in      HANDLE hFile,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpCreationTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastAccessTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastWriteTime
);
```

Its in winbase.h, so you just need to include windows.h

EDIT: I pasted the wrong function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933.aspx) API function.